# Redirect react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have a problem, watching a video on youtube that used `history.push('/login?redirect=shipping')`, how can I modify it using `navigate`, because if I use the string `navigate ('/ login?redirect=shipping')` even if logged in it returns to home page and does not go to the shipping page.

I solved the problem in this way :

```
 const checkoutHandler = () => {
       if(!userInfo){
          navigate('/login')
       } else{
          navigate('/shipping')
       }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to implement app/routing authentication? Can you share with us a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you want or are trying to do?

Comment: add sample https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Please share how the `Login` (*or whatever routed*) component is handling this redirect target is trying to navigate back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is good.
Can I fill in some gaps?

1. We need to get the state of user to check if user logged in to proceed with if statement.
2. After this your solution will work.

   ```
   import React from 'react'
   import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
   import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
   //....some imports

   const CartScreen = () => {
   //.......some code before
     const navigate = useNavigate()
     const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
     const { userInfo } = userLogin

     const checkoutHandler = () => {
       if (!userInfo) {
       navigate('/login')
       } else {
         navigate('/shipping')
       }
     }

     //...return JSX...
   ```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this one.

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
const checkoutHandler = () => {
    navigate('/signin?redirect=/shipping')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

```
navigate ('/login?redirect=/shipping')
```

Add forward slash '/' after redirect= before shipping,
Doing so, first login route will be executed then it will redirect to shipping.

Answer (score 0):

Have you sort out this problem or not? If you are facing the same problem then I suggest you go on your login page and make some changing.

Import useHistory and useLocation:

```
import { Link, useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Then in functions apply this:

```
const history = useHistory();
const location = useLocation();
```